# Twilio IVR with splitting based on caller id

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm new to Twilio IVR. I would like to create an IVR workflow where when a call comes in I get the number from the caller id, look it up in a database and if it exists take go down one path and if it's not in the database take another path. Can I do this with the visual designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Twilio Studio. You would use the HTTP Request Widget to submit the data to your DB and Split Based On... Widgets to process the result you return. The variable of the CallerID comes in to Studio from the Trigger Widget, **trigger.call.From**, which you can pass in your HTTP Request Widget to your application.

Studio Widget Library - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library

Studio User Guide - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#working-with-variables

Alan

Comment: Thanks, I realized I could use trigger.call.From in a Twilio Function, return a Javascript Object and split based on the ....parsed.key value. The flow context looks interesting though. Docs say I can set Flow variables with data return from a Function but it doesn't say how.